# After a certain time, the crawler engine stuck without showing any error/logs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, google-crawlers

After a certain time, the broad crawler engine stuck without showing any error/logs as you can
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXw2U.png). I had changed many time settings like integrated 15 dedicated IP Proxies, download_delay, concurrent_items and concurrent_requests, concurrent_requests_per_ip, etc but still facing this issue.

myspider.py

```
import datetime
import urllib3
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlsplit
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import CustomLinkExtractor
from ..items import BroadCrawlerItem
import collections
from ..extractors import DateExtractor, FaviconExtractor
import extraction
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import os
import tldextract
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class FollowAllSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'follow_all'  

    start_urls = [
        'https://news.google.com/topstories',
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates",
        "https://detailed.com/50/",
        "https://www.techlearning.com/news/15-awesome-article-sites-for-students",
        "https://jamesclear.com/articles",
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump',
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk'
    ]


    denylist = ['icann.org', 'blogspot.com', 'ganji.com', 'dihe.cn', 'google.com', 'twitter.com',
                'glassdoor.com', 'glassdoor.ie', 'youtube.com', 'wordcamp.com', 'wordcamp.org',
                'ganchang.cn', 'aa.com.tr', 'xinhuanet.com', 'nasdaq.com', 'aa.com.tr', 'wikipedia.org',
                'wikinews.org', 'wikimedia.org','indianexpress.com', 'whatsapp.com', 'edweek.org', 'apple.com',
                'facebook.com', 'reddit.com', 'linkedin.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 't.co', 'fzcom.cn', 'github.com',
                'amazon.com']

    rules = [Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(deny_domains=denylist), process_links='filter_links', follow=True, callback='parse_item')]
    count = 1


    def filter_links(self, links):
        for link in links:
            url = link.url.lower()
            if 'privacy' in url or 'forgot' in url or 'password' in url or 'developer' in url\
                or 'login' in url or 'twitter.com' in url or 'linkedin.com':
                continue
            yield link

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = BroadCrawlerItem()

        absolute_url = response.request.url
        domain = urlsplit(absolute_url)[0] + "://" + urlsplit(absolute_url)[1]
        title = self.get_title(response)
        meta_keywords = self.get_meta_keywords(response)
        extracted = extraction.Extractor().extract(response.body, source_url=absolute_url)
        meta_descripiton = self.get_meta_description(extracted)

        if not meta_descripiton:
            print('description not found..!')
            return

        print(f'{self.count} | {domain} | {absolute_url}')
        self.count += 1

        yield items
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'broad_crawler'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['broad_crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'broad_crawler.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'broad_crawler.pipelines.BroadCrawlerPipeline': 300,
}
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0
CONCURRENT_ITEMS = 15
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 20
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 8
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2
REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 20
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 8
USER_AGENT = 'my-bot'
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
RETRY_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE = 5592405
REDIRECT_ENABLED = False
AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED = True
LOG_LEVEL = 'WARN'

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
# SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler"
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.queue.PriorityQueue'
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter"
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = True
# REDIS_URL = "redis =//127.0.0.1 =6379"
```

Comment: Is there any activity on `LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'`?

Comment: no, there is no activity as well